# How to properly include ASM in a sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt

The scala compiler uses internally ASM for generating byte code. What is more proper way to include ASM in a scala sbt project: to get it somehow from scala compiler or to add as separate library dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ASM is used by Scala *internally*, you cannot use it without adding it as a dependency to you project.